# Can I generate seed for random numbers as static variable of a function?

Tags: c++, random, gsl, random-seed

In a really schematic way, my aim is to generate good-quality random numbers inside a function. I would like to seed the generator of random numbers with a static variable so I don't have to seed every time that I call the function.

I am generating the random numbers using the GSL library (https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/doc/html/rng.html). It is supposed to have better quality than the ones generated with `rand()` and in a more efficient way than the ones generated with the Mersenne Twister engine `std::mt19937`.

```
gsl_rng* Initialize() { //INITIALIZE
    int rand_seed = 77711;                    //any integer
    srand(time(NULL));
    const gsl_rng_type* gsl_rng_T;
    gsl_rng* r;                        //The random variable
    gsl_rng_env_setup();
    gsl_rng_default_seed = rand_seed;
    gsl_rng_T = gsl_rng_default;
    r = gsl_rng_alloc(gsl_rng_T);
    return r;
}

int random_int(int n) {  //Generate integer random variable in [0,n[
    static gsl_rng* r2 = Initialize(); //Initialize as static
    return gsl_rng_uniform_int(r2, n);
}

void Calculations(/*Variables that have nothing to do with the random numbers*/) {
    //Stuff
    int position = random_int(Info.I);
    //Info.I is an integer member of the class "Info", its value changes
    // with each call of the function "Calculations".
    //.
    //.
    //.
    return;
}
```

I have to call the function *Calculations()* a lot of times, the values of *position* at each call are highly correlated (not really random). I basically always obtain the same output for *position*.

I am quite new in C++, I am used to use FORTRAN and I apologize for the terrible coding!

In related questions I've seen that people define a class for the seed. Is there any benefit to doing this? Someone want to recommend a different method or random number generator?

Thank you very much :)

Comment: `int position==random_int(Info.I); ` is not valid, is it?. Please include the code that you use to inspect the numbers. How do you know that you always get the same number? There is no output in the code you posted

Comment: also read here: [mcve]

Comment: From the paper you link it uses `mt19937` by default and makes no claims to being more efficient.

Comment: You **should not** seed every time you call  the function. Seed **once**. (Yes, there are situations where you re-seed, but this isn't one of them)